# Alfresco Explorer - Unable to cancel editing of file as admin user

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco Explorer (v3.3) I can see a Working Copy of a HTML file, but I am unable to click on the **Cancel Editing** or **Done Editing** icons. The error message shown is:

> Unable to cancel check out of Content Node due to system error:010911608 Access Denied. You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.

I am logged in as admin, and the when I look at the details page for this item I see the the Modified user is admin.

How has this happened and how do I move forward? I need to make changes to this file.

**EDIT:** In response to comments ...

There was nothing in the log files (!!).

Unfortunately I can no longer check the permissions section (I mistakenly only looked at the Properties section previously), as in desperation I managed to delete the Working Copy file by (1) creating a temp folder, (2) moving the file to that folder and (3) deleting the folder.

I will probably close this question as it does not seem a satisfactory outcome, but thank you for your help.

Comment: Any errors in the Alfresco log?

Comment: check permission using node browser.and also paste that portion in question.